# How do I read a very long text from a notepad using C++?

Tags: c++, string, text, codeblocks

I have a notepad with a lot of characters *(around 10000, numbers, letters, quotation marks, etc)* and I want to read them all. I have tried several methods found online but none worked so far.

After I read the text, I also want to modify it by replacing one specific word. *(I know how to do this)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream file("export_descr_buildings.txt");
string content;

while(file >> content) {
cout << content ;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you talk us through some of the approaches you've tried so far and why they didn't work? If you post sample code that you've written, we can look over it and see whether there's an easy fix to one of the strategies you've attmpted.

Comment: What is a notepad? Do you mean a text file?
Please, state explicitly what methods you have tried and in what exact way did they fail.

Comment: 1. They failed because whenever I was trying to run the code, the output was 0 or nothing. Yes, I meant a text file.

Comment: For future context, "10000 characters" is not what most modern programmers would consider a "very long" text file. That's only 10kb, after all. There are lots of good solutions to reading a 10kb file, but they wouldn't be what the average programmer would come up with for reading a "very long text", which would intuitively suggest file sizes in the multi-GB range.

Comment: Can you show us the exact code that you were running? Without seeing the code, we can't tell whether the issue is something really simple (as in, the file is in the wrong place) or more nuanced (you're using a function in the wrong way.)

Comment: Now after you added the code, my guess is you have your text file in the wrong folder so it was not read at all.

Comment: The text is in the correct folder. I will try deleting it and putting it back, though.

Comment: Your program should check if the file is opened and print an error message if it is not able to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've posted will open the file `export_descr_buildings.txt` from the program's working directory and print out its contents (mostly - more on that later.) If you're not seeing anything at all, it likely means that the file couldn't be opened properly. You can check whether the file opened by writing something to this effect:

```
ifstream file("export_descr_buildings.txt");
if (!file) {
    // Report an error, and (probably) exit the program.
}
```

I'd start off by trying this to see whether the issue is whether the file can be opened at all. If not, that's the real issue, and then the question is why. The most likely culprit would be that the file is in the wrong directory, and you can try to fix that by moving the file around to different candidate locations until you can open it.

There's another issue here, and that's that the way that you're reading the file probably won't do what you want it to do. By default, if you write

```
file >> content;
```

the input will consume whitespace and only read up to whitespace. Therefore, if you have a file that contains the text

```
A B C D
```

you'll see printed as output

```
ABCD
```

because all the whitespace will be removed. If that's what you want to do, great! On the other hand, if you want to literally read the contents of the file and print them out, I'd recommend using this idiom:

```
for (string line; getline(file, line); ) {
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, though, I can't say for sure that this is the right pattern. That will depend on your use case.

Comment: EDIT: I managed to make it work, there was a problem with CodeBlocks. Thx.